# Using MYSQL replication to speed up Schema changes and table optermise

Tags: mysql, schema, replication, alter-table, master-slave

I hear that many people use master - slave arrangements help to improve time taken when changing schemas by using replication to setup a new temporary master, then stopping relocation and then swapping roles before starting again. I have found an example (below) found on stack overflow.

> 1. Setup slave
> 2. Stop replication.
> 3. Make ALTER on slave
> 4. Let slave catch up the master
> 5. swap master and slave, so slave becomes production server with changed
>      structure and minimum downtime

This is all very well, however, i dont understand step 4 it isn't clear to me.

I wonder if anyone could please explain the procedure clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let slave catch up the master

Let slave catch up with the master meaning slave is 0 seconds behind master.

This mean if the replication stopped at some point (for you to alter table),
it will register a last replication time.

When the replication resume,
it will compare the current write on master with the last replication time on slave.

However, the procedures seems to be a **flaw**.
You cannot alter slave and
expecting schema in the **updated slave** is same as **master**.

In the events column type changed, column dropped,
potentially lead to replication failure.

Comment: Thats what i was thinking how can data from the old schema be replicated into the new it doesn't work! any idea how to come up with a procedure that does?

Comment: I suppose only a script can do the job, unless I am missing something?

Comment: @andicrook - If down time allow, perform alter directly on master(alter will block table from read/write), and mysql will replicate the alter to each of your slave. How big is your database ? Currently, do you running any replication ?

Comment: @ajreal I am just learning about mysql scalability at the moment, what i am trying to achieve is how to make schema changes on large databases with minimal downtimes. I have read many documents from people explaining roughly how they achieve this many say by using master/slave replication and swapping master/slave rolls trick (like the above question) or by using master/master replication, however, they lack details or miss details out so I cant see the whole picture.

Comment: I understand what they are say is for the master/slave trick is that the replication link is broken, roles switched so the system is still up and then changes are made, however, the missing bit is how to get them synced again with out downtime

Comment: @andicrook - You can define a cut-off time. Once the slave promote to master, you can add back records inserted/update/delete after cut-off time from old master to new master (tricky, not so easy to detect, possible to dig from binary log). However, if you allow to use `flush tables with read lock` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html , that make whole transition easier (but this block write and put into queue)

Comment: I think the working on copy of the table instead, updating data then swapping trick is the best solution this is how facebook does it but is more of a scripted based solution.

Answer (score 0):

seconds_behind_master should be 0.

Comment: yes but the old data cant just be replicated into the new schema